# Promo images rejected on Chrome Webstore

Tags: image, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webstore

My promotional image was rejected by Google several times. What is the reason of this? I have no idea what's wrong. I prepared my promotional image according to guidelines, but still have weird alert "This small tile image has been rejected due to the following reason:
Other reasons". I wrote to Google several days ago but had no reply so far. The image is available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUAGv.png).

---

I wrote to Google five days ago. Still no answer. Now promotional image looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUAGv.png) and it's still being rejected due to "other reasons".

Comment: Yes, the extension allows to download movies from Youtube. The extension in available here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mdownloader/ofhiehmoknfecgggagakdcakpmajpnoo

Comment: have you contacted? cws-assets@google.com

Comment: May be the reason is `Avoid text`. according to https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images#promo

Comment: May work if you alter the `Youtube` logo. Don't use any Google trademarks or any confusingly similar marks as the name of your application or company without written permission from Google https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/branding#logos

Comment: Yes, as I wrote I contacted Google before but had no reply. (due to Christmas and New Year period I suppose). There are many promo images with text fields on it, but I will try your tip anyway.

Comment: @itsazzad, but it's not a general rule: "Feel free to continue using our badges in your application subject to the branding guidelines for each of those badges (for example, YouTube, Google Checkout)."

Comment: Yes you seems to be correct. So may be better you wait for the vacation being over.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

From my comments above:

have you contacted cws-assets@google.com ?

According to https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images#promo, the reason can be

> Avoid text

According to https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/branding#logos, May work if you alter the Youtube logo.

> Don't use any Google trademarks or any confusingly similar marks as
>   the name of your application or company without written permission
>   from Google

Comment: "have you contacted cws-assets@google.com ?". Yes, but had no reply. (due to Christmas and New Year period I suppose). It's not a general rule: Feel free to continue using our badges in your application subject to the branding guidelines for each of those badges (for example, YouTube, Google Checkout).